# Animación con javascript rotar cartas

Tags: javascript, animación

estoy haciendo una aplicación y una pantalla lleva animación, quiero que rote cartas pero me dice que es indefinido y no sé porque, lo probé solo, como si fuera una aplicación solo de la animación y me funcionaba, si lo pongo en la alicación grande no me funciona, me ayudan?

```
 var imagenes = new Array(
    'images/c0.jpg',
    'images/c1.jpg',
    'images/c2.jpg',
    'images/c3.jpg',
    'images/c4.jpg',
    'images/c5.jpg',
    'images/c6.jpg',
    'images/c7.jpg',
    'images/c8.jpg',
    'images/c9.jpg',
    'images/c10.jpg',
    'images/c11.jpg',
    'images/c12.jpg',
    'images/c13.jpg',
    'images/c14.jpg',
    'images/c15.jpg',
    'images/c16.jpg',
    'images/c17.jpg',
    'images/c18.jpg',
    'images/c19.jpg',
    'images/c20.jpg',
    'images/c21.jpg'
);

//Animación
function irAnimacion() {
    console.log('estoy en animacion');
    function rotarCartas() {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imagenes.length);
        document.getElementById('imag').src = imagenes[index];
    }

    console.log (rotarCartas())

    onload = function () {
        rotarCartas();
        setInterval(rotarCartas, 0300);
    };
    animacion.style.display = 'none';
    resultados.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122383/discussion-on-question-by-paula-animacion-con-javascript-rotar-cartas).

Comment: Esto esta resuelto? si es asi, pone una respuesta por favor. Si no, aclara tu duda en la pregunta...

Comment: no está resuelto, sigue sin funcionarme, lo que veo es que no ingresa a la función

Comment: Y donde deberia ingresar a la animacion?

Comment: paso la url así lo ves, pones los nombres click en jugar ahi entra la animación que sería que cambien las cartas y va a los resutados con un carrousel   https://theworldoftarot-pauclem.web.app

Comment: Toda la informacion, debe estar en la pregunta. El error debe ser reproducible (o estar) en la pregunta. Movi todos los comentarios aun chat porque no se entendia nada desde ahi. Por favor, usar el boton [edit] y agrega toda la informacion en la pregunta...